# How to add suffix to all files in local folder in linux mint?

Tags: files, linux-mint

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# addsuffix <suffix> <files>

suffix=$1
shift
for f in "$@"
do
  extension=${f##*.}
  if [ -z $extension ]; then
    mv "$f" "$f$suffix"
  else
    mv "$f" "${f%.$extension}$suffix.$extension"
  fi
done
```

by this command, where add_suffix is a name of previous file

```
sh add_suffix
```

but I get an error:

```
add_suffix: 5: shift: can't shift that many
```

What is wrong?

Comment: (1) by running `sh add_suffix`, you are circumventing the `bash` shebang (2) you are not providing any command line arguments, so there is nothing to `shift` (the same error can be demonstrated by `sh -c 'shift'`)

Comment: There's a bug in `extension=${f##*.}` which will only be an empty string (`[ -z $extension ]`) if file is an empty string. For file `a.txt` the extension will be `txt`, but for file `a` it is `a`. You could check `[ "$f" = "$extension" ]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering the question in the subject, not the question at the end of the post about what's wrong with the shell script.

If you are willing to do it outside of a shell script, the mmv command will do it.

```
me@elman:~/test$ ls
file1  file1.out  file2
me@elman:~/test$ mmv -n "*" "#1.newsuffix"
file1 -> file1.newsuffix
file1.out -> file1.out.newsuffix
file2 -> file2.newsuffix
```

The '-n' tells mmv to show what would be done, but not really do it (dry-run). The second argument ("*") tells mmv which files to alter (the source). You can have far more complicated match patterns, but this command should get all the non-hidden files in your directory. In the last argument "#1.newsuffix" (the destination), the #1 refers to the first wild-card match in the source specification and copies it over to the new name.

Remove the '-n' to really do the change. The manpage is very good.